# jquery coupon field not working after changing the addition code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys im new to coding and im trying to add a coupon code field to my form in contact form 7 in wordpress, the problem I had is that i assigned a value for adult and kid, and depending on the amount of each it would return the total value, but it was returning the value of both adult and kid even if there was only 1 adult and 0 kid, so i found a fix by using this code `subtotal = $("#subtotal").val(Number($("#adult").val()*35) + Number($("#kid").val()*18.40));` ,but know the couponcode field does not work, I would really appreciate your help, thanks.
[This is the link to the form im working on.](http://www.manawakieecopark.com/manawakie-park-sightseeing-island-tour/)

The code im using.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  //alert("Welcome");
  var adult;
  var kid;
  var subtotal;
  var total;
  var couponcode;

  jQuery("#adult, #kid").on("change", function () {
    adult = this.value;
    kid = this.value;

    subtotal = $("#subtotal").val(
      Number($("#adult").val() * 35) + Number($("#kid").val() * 18.4)
    );
    jQuery("#subtotal").val(subtotal.toFixed(2));
  });

  jQuery('input[name="couponcode"]').on("input keydown keyup", function (e) {
    let couponcode = jQuery('input[name="couponcode"]').val().trim();

    if (couponcode == "CCPPF") {
      total = subtotal * 0.1;
      jQuery("#total").val(total.toFixed(2));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Looks like the `id` attribute reference for the `total` input is `calc`, not total?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your site reference, which has changed since my previous comment:

[image]

The reference to: `jQuery("#total")`, should be: `jQuery("#totcalc")`

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your help, I already got that problem fixed, the problem i have now is with the auto calculation field, in order to show the result the field has to be clicked on, I cant figure out how to have the result show up without having to click on the field

Comment: ```jQuery("#calculation") .on("click" , function() {
  
        calculation = $("#calculation").val(Number($("#subtotal").val()) + 
        Number($("#total").val()));
        jQuery("#calculation").val(calculation.toFixed(2));   
        });```

Comment: That's the code im having problem with now, I cant figure out how to get the result to show without having to click on the field.